# jquery-carousel disappearing

Tags: wordpress, drupal, plugins, carousel

I'm using the [**jj-nextgen-jquery-carousel plugin**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jj-nextgen-jquery-carousel/) for wordpress, the problem I'm having with it is that the carousel disappears when I resize the browser. I'm not sure if this is a jQuery problem, or if the plugin is conflicting with the Twenty Ten theme?

```
<div id="jcarousel" style="display:block; width:885px; height:75px;">
<?php echo do_shortcode('[jj-ngg-jquery-carousel html_id="carousel-test-two" skin_class="jcarousel-skin-property" gallery="3" width="162" height="75" visible="5" gap="21" scroll="1" auto="1"]'); ?>
</div>
```

That's the code I'm using in my header.

Thanks

Comment: hi ho,
i have the same problem - when i resize the browser some pics are disapearing. have you find a solution on this?
thanks

Comment: Hi Dave, no I've not found any solutions, it might have something to with the size of each slide but who knows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug is documented here: https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel/issues/64

You can fix this issue if you edit the jcarousel.js file directly as described in comment #11 of the bug.

---

Change line 287 from this:

```
if (i + 1 < self.first) {
```

to this:

```
if (parseInt(jQuery(this).attr('jcarouselindex')) < self.first) {
```

Comment: Thanks mcbarron, that kinda works have some css issues to sort but that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Yah, I had to deal with a few CSS issues myself.  At least firefox and/or chrome have excellent tools to determine exactly why things look bad. :)